# Lynx: how to use -auth flag when username contains domain?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, lynx

I have a problem with Lynx. I'm trying to log in on a web page using the `-auth` flag. The line I use is

```
lynx -accept_all_cookies -auth=mydomain\myuser:mypass 
http://ultracooldomain.com/default.aspx
```

This does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong (if I login with the same user/pass combination in Lynx it works)?

Thanks
Nocklas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved it using -auth=mydomain\\myuser:mypass